# How to use WebSocket with php?

Tags: php, websocket

How to use WebSocket with php? Who can give me a example using php?. I need a full example to learn how to use websocket with php.

Comment: That's what google is for, isn't it?

Comment: See the sidebar with related question.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar if you edit his question please edit all typos. not only the title...

Answer (score 1):

There's an awesome lib for websockets in php:

Look at [this link](https://github.com/nicokaiser/php-websocket)

An example:

```
$server = new \Wrench\BasicServer('ws://localhost:8000', array(
    'allowed_origins' => array(
        'mysite.com',
        'mysite.dev.localdomain'
    )
));
$server->registerApplication('echo', new \Wrench\Examples\EchoApplication());
$server->registerApplication('chat', new \My\ChatApplication());
$server->run();
```

This creates a server on 127.0.0.1:8000 with one Application that listens for WebSocket requests to ws://localhost:8000/echo and ws://localhost:8000/chat:

An twitter api example here: http://jitt.li/